# ReactJS - How to set property on window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I've encountered an unfamiliar scenario. In my React project, I imported a 3rd party vendor api file. However, the vendor api makes internal calls using the Q promise library, which is not included. The api expects `window.Q` to be set and is a direct dependency of the api. I can't seem to figure out how to set this on window properly so that when I import the vendor file at the top of my source file and use it, it doesn't throw this error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$q.defer')`

global-variables.js:

Note: I imported the vendor library in this file because `ds` is a global variable created in the file for the consumer to make calls with.

```
import '../../vendor/vendor-library';

const globals = {
    DATA_SERVICE: ds,
};

export default globals;
```

user.js:

```
import globals from '../globals/global-variables';

const userApi = {
    getCurrentUser() {
        return globals.DATA_SERVICE.getDataForCurrentObject('User', 'ID');
    },
};

export default userApi;
```

I tried doing this at the top of my project entry point but it didn't solve the problem:

index.js:

```
import q from 'q';
window.Q = q;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty bad library. Unless it's required, I would probably reassess whether there's something better out there. Your app is only as secure as your least secure dependency...

Comment: FWIW, if you still do need to use it, you could probably do something like in this post: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/542

Comment: Hey Slider I am looking through your code and it would be helpful if you can give me more info on the vendor api you are working with.  It is odd to see 'Q' used in the manner that they 'require';  generally the 'q' I am familiar is an npm module.  A module that exists within the package.json.

Comment: Can't understand clearly. Maybe you need https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll take a look at those tomorrow. If you don't mind, here is the link to the vendor API: http://developer.veevacrm.com/MyInsightsLibrary/#myinsights-v2-0-beta. This is the file: https://cdnmc1.vod309.com/htmlreports/dataAccessLibrary.js. @MattFernandez If you'll look at it, you can see that they are expecting window.Q to be defined already. I tested in a vanilla app, just placing the Q library in a script tag, followed by this vendor api file in a script tag inside the html. I confirmed that this gets it to work. Just trying to do that now in a React app.

Comment: Hey Slider I went through all of the Veeva CRM documentation and there are no references to Q or promises.  Can you point me to or show me where you are seeing a need for the Q promise library?

Comment: @MattFernandez Take a look at the dataAccessLibrary.js file I posted above. In there, the code expects `window.Q` to be defined, and creates a variable `$q` to reference it. The rest of the api uses `$q` to make internal calls.

Comment: @kkSLider I looked through the dataAccessLibrary file.  $q is referenced throughout the document.  $q.defer() is also referenced.  I did not find other references to AngularJS though. This led me to believe that the problem is not with AngularJS but in reference to the Window.  I believe the virtual DOM that REACT uses is preventing access to the window. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081803/how-do-i-use-the-window-object-in-reactjs

the article talks about the same problem and I believe it might be able to help you. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input @MattFernandez. I tried the suggestion posted below and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an extension provided by either `webpack` or whatever other bundler you are using to bundle your javascript to provide Q as a global.

In webpack this can be done with the `webpack.ProvidePlugin`

Example:

```
module.exports = {
    module : {
       ...
    },
    plugins : [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Q: "q",
            "window.Q": "q",
        }),
   ],
};
```

In this case `"q"` is the name of the [Q library from npm](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), which you would have to add as a dependency to your project.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!