# (Unexpected Use of 'location') React with PubNub

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, pubnub

So I'm trying to build a chat-based application with React and Pubnub, along with Node.JS. Everything was going well throughout the App's creation, except for receiving an 'Unexpected Use of Location error' on the following line of code:

```
 Line 23: ssl: (location.protocol.toLowerCase() === 'https:'),    

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import Messages from './Messages.js';
    import MessageHistory from './MessageHistory.js';
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, NavLink, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Pubnub from 'pubnub';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
      this.state = {
            username: '',
            history: [],
      }
      this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.Pubnub = Pubnub.init({
        publish_key: 'pub-redacted',
        subscribe_key: 'sub-redacted',
        ssl: (location.protocol.toLowerCase() === 'https:'),
      });
      this.Pubnub.subscribe({
        channel: 'Somerset',
        message: (message) => this.setState({
          history: this.state.history.concat(message)
        })
      })
    }
      sendMessage = (message) => {
        this.Pubnub.publish({
          channel: 'Somerset',
          message: message,
        })
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
          <MessageHistory history={this.state.history} />
          <Messages username={this.state.username} sendMessage={this.sendMessage} />
          </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        );
      }
            }
             export default App;
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @CraigConover my fault Craig! Forgot to reply. Setting the SSL to true did the trick! Many thanks!

Comment: Great - I moved my comments to official answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Always use SSL

`location` object (a property of window) is not available in react/node like it is in the browser. [See this post on SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081803/how-do-i-use-the-window-object-in-reactjs) for more details.

But really no reason to not use SSL when initializing Pubnub object. I would recommend just setting it to true rather than using the protocol of app to conditionally set it.

```
this.Pubnub = Pubnub.init({
    publish_key: 'pub-redacted',
    subscribe_key: 'sub-redacted',
    // ssl: true
});
```