# How do you handle a script.src URL callback in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I can't seem to figure out how to fire a function based off google's script GET request.

```
export class Map extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    };

    componentDidMount = function () {
        console.log(google); // Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    };

    scriptInitialized = function () {
        console.log('scriptInitialized');
    };

    render() {

        let scriptInitialized = function () {
            console.log('scriptInitialized');
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <script type="text/javascript">/* nothing in here works */</script>
                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=scriptInitialized" defer async={true}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get *callback=scriptInitialized* to work. It works if I keep all the JavaScript related to the src in the index.html of my project but that makes things more complicated. It would be awesome to be able to keep things centralized to this component.

I know that there are third-party libraries for google maps but if possible I'd like to avoid them.

The only goal of this is to fire an event when the script is finished loading so I can use it without firing off a *"Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback from the google api is looking for `window.scriptInitialized`. You have the `scriptInitialized` tied to the component, not the window. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081803/how-do-i-use-the-window-object-in-reactjs) on how to add the function on the window in React