# how to make use of cdn URL Callback in react.js

Tags: reactjs, bing-maps

I'm have CDN which has parameter `callback`. The method value passed in this callback param will be called after script loaded.

```
https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=initializeReactBingMaps
```

How to use this callback method in react.js?

I declated `initializeReactBingMaps()` method in my component. But that didn't hit.

Note: Loaded this cdn using new script element in component constructor method.

Comment: This post can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438478/how-do-you-handle-a-script-src-url-callback-in-a-react-component

Answer (score 0):

Make the method static like

```
static initializeReactBingMaps()
```

Also set the callback to be the component name followed by the static method like

```
callback=myComponent.initializeReactBingMaps
```